# Can Hibernate generate uppercase SQL?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, uppercase

can Hibernate generate uppercase SQL?
I.e. some option which would make it send

```
SELECT table1_.prop1_ FROM my_table AS table1_;
```

instead of current

```
select table1_.prop1_ from my_table as table1_;
```

which I consider far less readable, esp. for long queries HBN tends to spit.
See also https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=932412

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it open source? Can't you just change the source code to do what you want?

Comment: Sure. And with any new version I will do it again and again and again. Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found: The King of the Hibernate team is strictly against such option:

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HB-1070

For anyone looking for this, please comment there (you can't vote on closed issues :( )

<strike>**Update:** Another solution is to replace the FreeMarker templates in hibernate's .jar's.</strike>

Comment: Huh? FreeMarkers templates for SQL generation? That would be new to me (to my knowledge, Hibernate Tools uses templates, not Hibernate).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way to upper case the keywords only out-of-the-box. But you could write your own interceptor and implement [`o.h.Interceptor#onPrepareStatement(String)`](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/hibernate/api/hibernate-core/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onPrepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29) to transform the sql string as you like.

Comment: You'd need to do some serious parsing work though to avoid capitalizing stuff that should be left as is (for example the word "select" inside a like where clause).

Comment: @cherouvim: Indeed, it's not that trivial. But its clearly doable.

Comment: Yes, doable. I've done it to add index hints. Probably not worth doing it though just for capitalizing. At least in production.

Comment: @cherouvim: I totally agree (using a "capitalizer interceptor" in production would generate useless overhead).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that this will enforce uppercase, but it does help with readability. In your *hibernate.cfg.xml* place the following in your `<session-factory>` element:

```
<!--hibernate.cfg.xml -->
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
```